# Как скопировать массив строк в буфер обмена?

Tags: c#

Как скопировать массив строк в буфер обмена ?

Comment: `textBox1.Copy()`

Comment: то не текст textBox, а массив string[] mas

Comment: Возможно это поможет: StringBuilder clipData = new StringBuilder();  
 
foreach (object value in arrayList)  
    clipData.AppendLine(value.ToString());  
 
Clipboard.SetText(clipData.ToString());

Comment: @ЭдикБилый огонь - то что нужно - спасибо